# why I cannot set the csv delimiter in cloud function to pipe

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have wrote a function that read csv file from cloud storage and load it to BigQuery.
the function is quite simple and straightforward however the csv file is pipe delimited and even if I set the job configuration filedelimiter to '|' it still do the partition on the comma ',' 
here is how the

```
def FlexToBigQuery(data, context):
    bucketname = data['bucket']
    filename = data['name']
    timeCreated = data['timeCreated']

    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_id = 'nature_bi'
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('Anstallningsnummer', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Datum', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Kod', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Kostnadsstalle', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Tidkod', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('OB_tidkod', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Dagsschema', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Schemalagd_arbetstid', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Summa_narvaro', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Summa_franvaro', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Datum_for_klarmarkering', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Datum_for_attestering', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Frislappsdatum', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Export_klockslag', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Vecka', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE')
    ]

    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 0
    job_config.fieldDelimiter = '|',
    job_config.allow_jagged_rows = True
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    # log the receipt of the file
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    uri = 'gs://%s/%s' % (bucketname, filename)
    print('Received file "%s" at %s.' % (
        uri,
        timeCreated
    ))


    "1121|51.2|130|1|2019-08-05 09:06|2019-08-05 11:27|ARB|2019-07-01 null null null null null null null null null"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCP Support here! I've noticed that you are using `job_config.fieldDelimiter` instead of `job_config.field_delimiter` as stated in [this](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.field_delimiter) documentation, this is probably your issue.

I'd suggest trying this and if the issue persists add any errors if shown to your original answer. I would be also helpful if you could share the guide you are following if any.

Comment: Thank you for this! Had the same issue. But this documentation says the API property is fieldDelimiter.  This is where the confusion was https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options